# Plural of titles (Mr. and Dr.)

Tags: grammar

Good morning!

Is there any plural form for titles? For instance, may I say?

(a) I was supervised by **professors** Dr. John Robinson and Dr. Peter Simpson

(b) I need to talk to **misters** Peter Coley and Leonardo More

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr.   Probably a Google search should have been tried first.

Comment: (b) is [Messrs](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/messrs) in Britain.

Comment: I can’t see it mentioned in the Wikipedia article, but in the modern English-speaking world the formal instances in which you would ever pluralise titles like Mr and Mrs have dwindled to the point I would almost note them as “rare” but not yet “obsolete”.

Comment: I notice too that “professors” here is unlikely to be a title. Titles incorporating multiple roles/statuses like “Professor Doctor Schmidt” only exist in other languages like German I believe. The sentence (a) seems to be using professors as if it was a description of the people not their title. If so, you must rephrase as, “I was supervised by THE professors, Dr John...”

Comment: Thank you very much! It is much more clear now.

Comment: A last question: if I choose to call someone as "professor" - omitting "Dr" -, it would be (A) supervised by professors Robinson and Simpson or (B) supervised by THE professors Robinson and Simpson? Summarising, omitting "Dr", it is still necessary to employ the article THE?